# why can't i send data from Activity to Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

> 1. ACTIVITY 1: SEND DATA(MA_NV) TO  SWIPMENU_CONTROL public class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   

    public Button DangKy_Btn;   
    public Button DangNhap_Btn;     
    public EditText MaNV_Edit;  
    public EditText Password_Edit;  
    public CheckBox TrangThai_CB;   
    public TextView MaNV_Info;

    DBAdapter db;   
    String prefname="my_status";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db= new DBAdapter(MainActivity.this);

        DangKy_Btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.DangKy_Btn);
        DangKy_Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override       
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                Intent myIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,dang_ky.class);           
                startActivity(myIntent);        
            }   
        });

        MaNV_Edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.MaNV_Edit);
        MaNV_Info=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.MaNV_Info);
        Password_Edit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password_Edit);
        TrangThai_CB=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.TrangThai_CB);
        DangNhap_Btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.DangNhap_Btn);
        DangNhap_Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String Ma_NV=MaNV_Edit.getText().toString();
                String Mat_Khau=Password_Edit.getText().toString();
                db.open();
                Cursor c=db.Check_Login(Ma_NV,Mat_Khau);

                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    do_Login(Ma_NV);
                }
                else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thất bại",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                db.close();
            }
        });
    }

    public void do_Login(String Ma_NV){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Ma_NV, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SwipMenu_Control.class);
        Bundle myBundle=new Bundle();
        myBundle.putString("manv",Ma_NV);
        myIntent.putExtra("Ma_NV",myBundle);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause(); //GOI HAM LUU TRANG THAI
        savingPreferences();
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume(); //GOI HAM DOC TRANG THAI
        restoringPreferences();
    }

    public void savingPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences pre=getSharedPreferences(prefname,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pre.edit();
        String Ma_NV= MaNV_Edit.getText().toString();
        String Pass=Password_Edit.getText().toString();
        boolean trangthai=TrangThai_CB.isChecked();

        if(!trangthai){
            editor.clear();
        }else{
            editor.putString("Ma_NV", Ma_NV);
            editor.putString("Password", Pass);
            editor.putBoolean("Checked",trangthai);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void restoringPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences pre=getSharedPreferences(prefname,MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean trangthai=pre.getBoolean("Checked",false);
        if(trangthai)
        {
            String Ma_NV=pre.getString("Ma_NV","");
            String Pass =pre.getString("Password", "");
            MaNV_Edit.setText(Ma_NV);
            Password_Edit.setText(Pass);
            //Dang nhap vao luon
            /*  db.open();
            Cursor c=db.Check_Login(Ma_NV,Pass);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do_Login(Ma_NV);
            }
            else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thất bại",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();*/
        }
        TrangThai_CB.setChecked(trangthai);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 
}
```

2.ACTIVITY 2: SEND DATA(MA_NV) TO FRAGMENT_PRODUCT

> ```
> public class SwipMenu_Control extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
>
>     /**
>      * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
>      * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
>      * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
>      * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
>      * may be best to switch to a
>      * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
>      */
>     SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
>
>     /**
>      * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
>      */
>     ViewPager mViewPager;
>
>
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.swipview_main);
>
>         Intent callerIntent= getIntent();
>         Bundle packageFromCaller=callerIntent.getBundleExtra("Ma_NV");
>         String MaNV= packageFromCaller.getString("manv");
>
>         Fragment fragInfo = new Fragment();
>         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
>         bundle.putString("manv", MaNV );
>         fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
>
>          // Set up the action bar.
>         final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
>         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
>
>         // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
>         // primary sections of the activity.
>         mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
>
>         // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
>         mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
>
>         mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
>
>         // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
>         // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
>         // a reference to the Tab.
>
>         mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onPageSelected(int position) {
>                 actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
>             }
>         });
>
>         // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
>         for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
>             // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
>             // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
>             // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
>             // this tab is selected.
>             actionBar.addTab(
>                     actionBar.newTab()
>
>                             .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
>                             .setTabListener(this));
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>         int id = item.getItemId();
>         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>             return true;
>         }
>         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
>         // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
>         // the ViewPager.
>         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
>      * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
>      */
>     public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
>
>         public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
>             super(fm);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>             // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
>             // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
>             switch(position){
>               case 0: return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
>               case 1: return Fragment_Product.newInstance(position);
>               case 2: return Fragment_Accout.newInstance(position);
>               default:return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
>             }
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public int getCount() {
>             // Show 3 total pages.
>             return 3;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
>             Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
>             switch (position) {
>                 case 0:
>                     return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
>                 case 1:
>                     return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
>                 case 2:
>                     return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
>             }
>             return null;
>         }
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
>      */
>
>     public static class PlaceholderFragment  extends Fragment{
>
>         /**
>          * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
>          * fragment.
>          */
>
>         private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
>
>         /**
>          * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
>          * number.
>          */
>         public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
>             PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
>             Bundle args = new Bundle();
>             args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
>             fragment.setArguments(args);
>             return fragment;
>         }
>
>         public PlaceholderFragment() {
>
>
>         }
>
>         private Button Add_Guest;
>         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>
>           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guest, container, false);
>           final String myValue = getArguments().getString("manv");
>           if(myValue!=null){
>           Add_Guest =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Btn_Add_Guest);
>             Add_Guest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>               @Override
>               public void onClick(View v) {
>                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                   Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Add_Guest.class);
>                   Bundle myBundle=new Bundle();
>                   myBundle.putString("Ma_NV", myValue);
>                   intent.putExtra("manhanvien", myBundle);
>                   getActivity().startActivity(intent);
>               }
>           });
>           }
>           else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "haiz", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return rootView;
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     public static class Fragment_Product extends Fragment {
>         /**
>          * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
>          * fragment.
>          */
>         private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
>
>         /**
>          * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
>          * number.
>          */
>         public static Fragment_Product newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
>             Fragment_Product fragment = new Fragment_Product();
>             Bundle args = new Bundle();
>             args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
>             fragment.setArguments(args);
>             return fragment;
>         }
>
>         public Fragment_Product() {
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
>
>             return rootView;
>         }
>         public static class Fragment_Accout extends Fragment {
>             /**
>              * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
>              * fragment.
>              */
>             private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
>
>             /**
>              * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
>              * number.
>              */
>             public static Fragment_Accout newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
>                 Fragment_Accout fragment = new Fragment_Accout();
>                 Bundle args = new Bundle();
>                 args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
>                 fragment.setArguments(args);
>                 return fragment;
>             }
>
>             public Fragment_Accout() {
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>                 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accout, container, false);
>                 return rootView;
>             }
>     }
>     }
>     @Override
>     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
>         //Handle the back button
>         if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
>             //Ask the user if they want to quit
>             new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
>             .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
>             .setTitle("QUIT")
>             .setMessage("BAN CO CHAC CHAN MUON THOAT")
>             .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
>
>                     //Stop the activity
>                     SwipMenu_Control.this.finish();    
>                 }
>
>             })
>             .setNegativeButton("NO", null)
>             .show();
>
>             return true;
>         }
>         else {
>             return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
>         }
>
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onBackPressed() {
>         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
>             .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
>             .setTitle("Closing Activity")
>             .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
>             .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
>         {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
>               SwipMenu_Control.this.finish();    
>             }
>
>         })
>         .setNegativeButton("No", null)
>         .show();
>     }
> }
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>         int id = item.getItemId();
>         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>             return true;
>         }
>         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> 3.

```
> 10-16 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852): java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Could not find a method Add_Guest(View) in the activity class
> theanh.quanly.SwipMenu_Control for onClick handler on view class
> android.widget.Button with id 'Btn_Add_Guest' 10-16 12:03:47.793:
> E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
> 10-16 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 10-16 12:03:47.793:
> E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-16 12:03:47.793:
> E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-16 12:03:47.793:
> E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 10-16 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-16 12:03:47.793:
> E/AndroidRuntime(852): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> Add_Guest [class android.view.View] 10-16 12:03:47.793:
> E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
> java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423) 10-16
> 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
> java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787) 10-16 12:03:47.793:
> E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
> 10-16 12:03:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Any logs or error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can send data from activity to Fragment by using Listener,Abstract class or Constructor. hope You Understand.